# How can I define the color of my Navbar from Materialize CSS codes that I've used

Tags: python, css, django, navbar, materialize

newbie here, the navbar default color is materialize red I want to change it to light blue:

```
<nav>
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <a href="/" class="brand-logo">LARAYAN ONLine BookStore</a>
  <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

go to https://materializecss.com/color.html and from the color pallete, select the color you want, and paste it in the nav class, for example, **blue-grey lighten-3**

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper blue-grey lighten-3"> <!--Paste your color here-->
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: thanks  for your help Ahmad... I can define now the color of my navbar